# Kentico - staging tasks processing automation

Tags: kentico

Is there out of the box function in *Kentico 11 CMS* to configure automatical deletion of old staging tasks? Can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no task out of the box and shouldn't be. If you want to do that you'd need to create that task on your own. Not quite sure why you'd want though. Kind of defeats the purpose of staging.

You can also so this through a SQL query although it requires you to touch at least 5 different tables.

Comment: Just to add to Brenden, processed staging tasks should be deleted automatically, which means only errors should stay in place and these should be investigated and retried as it suggests there is a problem with either service or data.